# How can I use the quadratic formula when the y is reversed?

Tags: math, graph, quadratic

When you graph a parabola on a normal graph, you can use ax^2+bx+c but when I want to graph a parabola in a window, This doesn't work for me.  I assume this is because the y axis is reversed.  Is there a workaround or a different formula to counter this?  For example, if I have a player at (100,150) and I am trying to shoot an arrow at an apple at (500,150)  How would I do this?  I am trying to stay pure to math without getting to complicated.  I am still in high school, and am just learning about these so please try to keep it simple.  My math teacher mentioned something about quadratic regression, what is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to address this is to have two different coordinate systems, one for the screen and another for your model.

The `y` axis of the screen would point down. The `y` axis of your model up. Both systems will share the very same `x` axis.

Now, the idea is: **think using your model's coordinates and map them to the screen only for display.**

The transformation that maps a point with coordinates `(x, y)` in one system to the other is

```
(x, y) -> (x, h - y)
```

where `h` is the heigh of your screen (`h > 0`).

The inverse transformation (i.e., the one that maps the screen onto your model) is the same because from the viewpoint of the upward `y` axis the screen `y` axis is also at distance `h` from its origin.

Applying this to your equation your model would have points of the form

```
(x, ax^2 + bx +c)
```

and these would map to points

```
(x, h -ax^2 - bx -c) = (x, -ax^2 - bx + h-c)
```

in screen coordinates.